# How to fix array index out of bounds error?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

The error that I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 610
at Fib.sorted(Fib.java:67)
at Fib.main(Fib.java:17)
```

My code

```
public class Fib
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString( fiblist) );
        System.out.println(Fib.add());
        System.out.println(Fib.square());
        System.out.println(Fib.reversal());
        System.out.println(Fib.sorted());
    }

     public static int fiblist[] = {1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765};
     public static int fiblen = fiblist.length;

     public Fib() 
     {
        // Do nothing
     }

     public static ArrayList<Integer> sorted()
     {
         ArrayList sorted = new ArrayList();

         for(int counter = 0; counter < fiblist[4]; counter++ )
         {
             int temp1 = fiblist[counter];
             System.out.println("Elements stored " + temp1);
         }
         for(int counter = fiblist[14]; counter < fiblist[19]; counter++)
         {
             int temp2 = fiblist[counter];
             System.out.println("Last Elements stored " + temp2);
         }
         return sorted;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to store the last 5 elements of my array in temp 2.
Then I will switch them. 
Is there an easier way to do this?
Switch the first five elements of an array with the last five?
How would you switch them with a for loop?

Comment: Your `counter` should be the position in the array and not the value of that position. Change `counter < fiblist[4]` to `counter < 4` and change `int counter = fiblist[14]` to `int counter = 14` to fix the problem.

Comment: This looks like trouble `int counter = fiblist[14]; counter < fiblist[19];` since you are getting values way higher than your list size

Comment: And also `counter < fiblist[19]` to `counter < 19`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
for(int i=0;i<fiblist.length;i++){
   System.out.print(fiblist[i]+",");
}
System.out.println();

for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
    temp=fiblist[i];
    fiblist[i]=fiblist[fiblist.length-i-1];
    //the first ellement= the last
    //the second=second from last...
    fiblist[fiblist.length-1-i]=temp;
}

for(int i=0;i<fiblist.length;i++){
    System.out.print(fiblist[i]+",");
}
```

Output:

```
1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,
6765,4181,2584,1597,987,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,5,3,2,1,1,
```

Comment: would temp just display the 'movement'?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing array index and value. fiblist[19] is 6765. You want your counters to go from 0 to 4 and 14 to 19, not fiblist[19].

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++ )
{
    int temp1 = fiblist[counter];
    System.out.println("Elements stored " + temp1);
}

for(int counter = 14; counter < 19; counter++)
{
    int temp2 = fiblist[counter];
    System.out.println("Last Elements stored " + temp2);
}
```

Comment: Don't just copy and paste the OP's formatting and correct the problem with the code, fix the formatting so people don't have to edit both the question _and_ your answer.

Comment: This part runs. but how do I move temp1 to the end of an array? Or temp2 to the beginning of the array?

Comment: @vDc put fiblist[19] in a variable, set fiblist[19] = fiblist[0], then put the value of your variable in fiblist[0].

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's a sorting algorithm (A fairly poor one though)

```
public static void sort(int[] a) {
    int iMin;
    int n = a.length;
    for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
        iMin = j;
        for (int i = j+1; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[iMin]) {
                iMin = i;
            }
        }
        if(iMin != j) {
            swap(j, iMin, a);
        }
    }
}

public static void swap(int i, int j, int[] arr){
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```