# Why my thymeleaf #strings is not working?

Tags: string, substring, thymeleaf

There is a table on the html that I'm working on, and for one column I want to show up to 30 characters (because it can be very long). Below is my code but it's not working and I cannot figure out why. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

```
<span th:text="${#strings.substring(history.keyword,0,30)} + '…'"></span>
```

Comment: are you facing any error? Also on a side note you can do this before sending it to your Thymeleaf page.

Comment: Despite this is not the answer to your question, You shouldn't use Thymeleaf for string truncation with ellipsis, because different letters will have different width in px, unless you are using mono font. Instead, you should consider a simple CSS approach to truncate strings to fit into the column.

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment. I found out that the reason my codes weren't working was because I didn't condition the length of the letters.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this to work, you need to account for those strings which may be less than your limit of 30 characters. The above approach will fail in such cases (with a Java [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149182/how-to-fix-array-index-out-of-bounds-error)).

There are different ways around this. One way is to use the Thymeleaf "if/else" syntax (`(if) ? (then) : (else)`) to handle this - for example:

```
<block th:with="kwd=${history.keyword}, len=${#strings.length(history.keyword)}">
    <span th:text=" ( ${len > 30} ) 
          ? ${#strings.substring(kwd,0,30)} + '…'
          : ${kwd}"></span>
</block>
```

The other thing I used in the above approach was `th:with` to create 2 variables: `kwd` and `len` to make the if/else statement more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! As you wrote, the reason of not working was because I didn't take the length of the letters into consideration. Now I got the codes working. thanks again!